# When I add or derive columns, subsequent data flow transformations don't see the new columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there a way to "cascade" new column information down through the subsequent data flow transformations when I add a new column?  My current practice is to open each tranformation in sequence and verify that the new column is available.  If it isn't, I delete and recreate the transformation.  I can't believe there isn't a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already created the data flow and then alter or add a derived column transformation, the data flow usually doesn't automatically update subsequent transformations.  However, your approach to open (edit) each transformation in sequence should force the transformation to update.

I don't recall any times where a transformation doesn't update with new inputs, but when it happens to you, you might want to delete and recreate the data-flow path.  You may have less work to do to recreate the data-flow path.

Comment: Somehow I feel better going through these steps when there isn't an obvious easier approach. Thanks again SO and bobs.